# Why is my favicon not updating on my GitHub pages website and in the repo?

Tags: git, ipad, safari, jekyll

I have a very, very confusing situation. I am creating a blog in Github Pages. I have used a theme called Chirpy. I have gone through four repos with the theme and only two of theme have worked. One of them had a modified favicon (not the one I wanted, I had forked another guy’s repo), but it didn’t work in the end. I made a new repo with the same theme and uploaded my own favicon in the correct directory. But after deleting the old repo, the favicon is still there on the GitHub Pages repo page and the Github Pages site. I have cleared my cookies on everything Github, and the right favicon displays on all the other devices I have, but not my iPad which I was using to add the favicon to the repo. Do you guys have any tips to remedy this? I tried everything to get rid of that old favicon but it just won’t disappear.

The repo link: https://github.com/Kizuo/kizuo.github.io

It probably won’t show up for you guys as the wrong favicon but I just can’t get rid of it on the iPad. Everything else works!

Answer (score 0):

This is the favicon I see on https://kizuo.github.io:

[image: https://kizuo.github.io] (https://kizuo.github.io/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico)

If the image is not the same on your iPad, make sure to clear the cache of your browser (assuming you don't have any other settings you might want to keep)

- Reopen Safari, navigate to your site
- Navigate to the Settings App.
- Tap Safari on the left side.
- Tap Clear Website Data for your site.

[image: https://www.igeeksblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Remove-Specific-Website-Data-from-Safari-in-iPhone-Settings.jpg]

Comment: I did that, it didn’t help.

Comment: I still have that bad favicon on the Github Pages repo and the Github Pages site after deleting all my cookies.

Comment: @Delta135 Cookies have nothing to do with data. You need to delete a website data, not website cookies.

Comment: I know. I did what you told me to do earlier about four times with everything. But I only did it for the github sites. Do I have to do it for everything for it to work?

Comment: @Delta135 Normally I would say no, but in this instance... maybe. Although it could have consequences on other sites you could have persistent data you wanted to keep, so proceed with caution. Check first if, on that browser, the URL alone https://kizuo.github.io/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico shows the right icon.

Comment: It displays correctly. I have about 200 sites I want to keep data on but I will clear everything if I have to. Safari sucks :(

Comment: @Delta135 Would https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/09/08/refresh-favicons-in-safari-mac/ work?

Comment: I cleared all the site data and it still doesn’t work. I restarted it but I will restart it again.

Comment: Yeah, I restarted and cleared my safari browsing history eight times and it still hasn’t changed.